# eWay Client Side Encryption

Tags: php, client-side-scripting, eway

Is this possible?

I have a ecommerce website that has a eWay Payment Gateway, so I wanted to get the encrypted card details with the use of the client side encryption key that can be seen in the code `$(".form").attr("data-eway-encrypt-key", "The encryption key is placed here");` I wonder if this is possible because I want to pass the encrypted data to another form here is the link of encrytion js https://secure.ewaypayments.com/scripts/eCrypt.js

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar thing, not exactly sure where you need help from your question but this is my code. I use "RealCardNumber" as a text field and "CardNumber" as a hidden field that gets populated with the encrypted data and sent to the server (same for card code).

```
   $.getScript("https://secure.ewaypayments.com/scripts/eCrypt.min.js")
       .done(function (script, textStatus) {
           if (eCrypt !== undefined) {
               $('#card-details').show(); // Form details initially hidden
               $('#card-loading').hide(); // Placeholder div shown while loading the eWay script (which should happen pretty quick)
               // Setup the hooks to encrypt the card number once it is submitted
               $(".payment-info-next-step-button")[0].onclick = null; // This is the payment button in my scenario
               $(".payment-info-next-step-button").click(function () {
                   var eWayKey = "<Key goes here>"; // Get from Settings ....
                   try {
                       $('#CardNumber').val(eCrypt.encryptValue($('#RealCardNumber').val(), eWayKey));
                       $('#CardCode').val(eCrypt.encryptValue($('#RealCardCode').val(), eWayKey));
                       // Ready to go .... hook in your normal submit here
                   } catch (e) {
                       alert('Sorry there was a problem with submitting the card details securely');
                       console.log(e);
                   }
               });
           } else {
               $('#card-loading').hide();
               alert('eWay not available - please select a different payment method if available');
           }
       })
       .fail(function (jqxhr, settings, exception) {
           $('#card-loading').hide();
           alert('eWay not available - please select a different payment method if available');
       });
```